# New options for select (loop function)

Tags: javascript, loops

I am making an easy function that adds  new options (number from 0 to 12) by using loop.

However on th list I can see only last record (12) insted of all of them.
I was checking on console and there I can see all the numbers.

Do you have any idea what can be wrong in this code?

```js
function loop (j) {
  var j = 0;
  while (j<=12) {
    console.log(j);
    hours.innerHTML = "<option>" + j + "</option>";
    j++;
  };
};

loop();
```

```css
#alarm {
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="alarm">
    <p>Choose time of alarm ring</p>
    <select id="hours">
    </select>
    <select id="min">
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using a `for` loop? `for (var j = 0; j <= 12; j++) {}`?

Comment: @SamVK no, there is no reason ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not ***adding*** new options, you are ***replacing*** the previous one with a new one because you are wiping out the old `.innerHTML` with new HTML by using `=`.

If you use **`+=`** instead of **`=`** you will be adding new options to the existing ones.

```js
function loop (j) {
var j = 0;
while (j<=12) {
  //console.log(j);
  hours.innerHTML += "<option>" + j + "</option>";
  j++;
};
};

loop();
```

```css
#alarm {
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="alarm">
    <p>Choose time of alarm ring</p>
    <select id="hours">
    </select>
    <select id="min">
    </select>
  </div>

</body>
```

Having said that, there are several down sides to using `.innerHTML` as it causes the HTML parser to have to re-parse the document and that is wasteful and causes a performance hit. Using it in a loop is even more wasteful. There can also be security issues when using `.innerHTML` and event binding can be thrown off with it.

Instead, it is recommended to use the DOM API and create new DOM elements in memory and then append them as a single unit, just once, when the loop is done.

```js
function loop () {
  // Create a container element in memory only
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  // While loops can lead to bugs, use for loops instead when possible
  for(i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    var op = document.createElement("option");  // Create a new DOM element in memory only
    op.textContent = i;                         // Configure the element
    frag.appendChild(op);                       // Append it to the documentFragment
  };
  
  // Now that the loop is done and all the elements have been made,
  // append the elements to the DOM in one batch action
  document.getElementById("hours").appendChild(frag);
};

loop();
```

```css
#alarm {
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div id="alarm">
    <p>Choose time of alarm ring</p>
    <select id="hours">
    </select>
    <select id="min">
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Indeed! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Scott_Marcus thanks once again for time and explanation!